# Error - ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff

Tags: python, numpy, audio, jupyter-notebook, ipython

i am trying to break apart a wav file into smaller groups, mess around with it , and try to put it together again, but right at the end i get the error in the title, i was hoping that someone versed in python and numpy could explain to me what am i doing wrong, why am i getting this error.

Thank you very much

```
    path = 'C:/Users/example/Documents/folder/'
    Fs, xSom = wavfile.read('sample.wav')
    xSom_ = xSom[:Fs*2]
    #print(np.array_split(xSom_,37))
    for i in range(37):
        hrtf100 = np.fromfile(path + 'beep' + str(i*10).zfill(3) + 'boop.dat', dtype='short')
        hrtf100.dtype
        hrtf100.shape
        hrtf100_L = hrtf100[0::2]
        hrtf100_R = hrtf100[1::2]
        hrtf100_R_F = hrtf100_R.astype(np.float64)
        hrtf100_L_F = hrtf100_L.astype(np.float64)
        hrtf100_R_F_N = hrtf100_R_F/np.abs(np.max(hrtf100_R_F))
        hrtf100_L_F_N = hrtf100_L_F/np.abs(np.max(hrtf100_L_F))
        xSom_split = np.array_split(xSom_,37)[i]
        xSom_split.dtype
        xSom_F = xSom_split.astype(np.float64)
        xSom_F.dtype
        xSom_F_N = xSom_F / np.abs(np.max(xSom_F))
        out_L = np.convolve(hrtf100_L_F_N, xSom_F_N)
        out_R = np.convolve(hrtf100_R_F_N, xSom_F_N)
        out_L = out_L / np.abs(np.max(out_L))*(2**15-1)
        out_R = out_R / np.abs(np.max(out_R))*(2**15-1)
        out = np.zeros((len(out_L),2))
        out[:,0] = out_L
        out[:,1] = out_R
        if i>0:
            full_signal = np.concatenate((full_signal,out))
        else:
            full_signal = out

    display(Audio(data = full_signal.astype(np.int16), rate= Fs))
```

Error

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23744\379706904.py in <module>
----> 1 BinauralRotativo()

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23744\2326583148.py in BinauralRotativo()
     32             full_signal = out
     33 
---> 34     display(Audio(data = full_signal.astype(np.int16), rate= Fs))

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\display.py in __init__(self, data, filename, url, embed, rate, autoplay, normalize, element_id)
    115             if rate is None:
    116                 raise ValueError("rate must be specified when data is a numpy array or list of audio samples.")
--> 117             self.data = Audio._make_wav(data, rate, normalize)
    118 
    119     def reload(self):

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\display.py in _make_wav(data, rate, normalize)
    147         waveobj.setsampwidth(2)
    148         waveobj.setcomptype('NONE','NONE')
--> 149         waveobj.writeframes(scaled)
    150         val = fp.getvalue()
    151         waveobj.close()

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wave.py in writeframes(self, data)
    436 
    437     def writeframes(self, data):
--> 438         self.writeframesraw(data)
    439         if self._datalength != self._datawritten:
    440             self._patchheader()

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wave.py in writeframesraw(self, data)
    425         if not isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray)):
    426             data = memoryview(data).cast('B')
--> 427         self._ensure_header_written(len(data))
    428         nframes = len(data) // (self._sampwidth * self._nchannels)
    429         if self._convert:

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wave.py in _ensure_header_written(self, datasize)
    466             if not self._framerate:
    467                 raise Error('sampling rate not specified')
--> 468             self._write_header(datasize)
    469 
    470     def _write_header(self, initlength):

c:\users\example\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\wave.py in _write_header(self, initlength)
    483             self._nchannels * self._framerate * self._sampwidth,
    484             self._nchannels * self._sampwidth,
--> 485             self._sampwidth * 8, b'data'))
    486         if self._form_length_pos is not None:
    487             self._data_length_pos = self._file.tell()

error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= 0xffff
```

Comment: `ushort` is `uint16`. Try changing `display(Audio(data = full_signal.astype(np.int16), rate= Fs)) ` to `display(Audio(data = full_signal.astype(np.uint16), rate= Fs))`

Comment: I still get the same error